# Why my setting with NFS and setuid not working in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, root, nfs, setuid

I'm using Linux. On machine A I have such NFS setting in `etc/exports`:

```
/home 10.0.129.130(rw,no_root_squash)
```

I mount this directory on machine A on `/home/nfs/` on machine B. And I've set setuid using `chmod u+x program1.sh`.

On machine B I want user `xyz` to run the `program1.sh` using root privilege. The setting of `program1.sh` is like below:

```
-rwsr-x--- 1 root house 1299 May 15 23:54 program1.sh
```

, which contains `mkdir -p /home/nfs/house/nsx/`

I set `xyz` to be in the group `house` so that `xyz` can run `program1.sh`. However when running  `program1.sh`, it shows:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/nfs/house/nsx/': Permission denied
```

Running `program1.sh` as root is OK. I don't know why it's not working with user `xyz`.

Answer (score 1):

From the name `program.sh`, I am guessing that you're trying to run an interpreted script, not an ELF binary. Linux has [ignored the setuid bit](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#setuid) on scripts since long ago, due to possible security issues (race condition between kernel checking the +s bit, and script interpreter opening the file).

If this script needs to be available to specific users, create a `sudo` rule in /etc/sudoers that allows this:

```
xyz ALL=(root:root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/program.sh
```

There might be other solutions. For example, if you want to create home directories automatically (upon first login), the `pam_mkhomedir.so` PAM module exists for this.

Answer (score 0):

Because only `root` and user `nfs` have permissions on files/folders under: `/home/nfs`

Comment: I've set setuid using `chmod u+x`. Isn't this mean I can run this program as root. Like `passwd`, its privilege is `-rwsr-xr-x` so other users can run that as root.